# How to create multiple devices in a /dev/ subdirectory (kernel driver)

Tags: kernel-modules, devices

I'm writing a kernel module. I can easily create a character device in /dev/ but I want to have **3 devices** available to my user and it would be nice to put them all under a **/dev/ subdirectory**.

Possible example (exists on my openSUSE box):

```
# ls -l /dev/bsg
total 0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 252, 0 Jul 17 14:28 0:0:0:0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 252, 1 Jul 17 14:28 0:0:1:0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 252, 2 Jul 17 14:28 0:0:2:0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 252, 3 Jul 17 14:28 0:0:3:0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 252, 4 Jul 17 14:28 0:0:4:0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 252, 5 Jul 17 14:28 1:0:0:0
```

(I have looked at the bsg.c code but am at a loss to what "parent" the character devices are added to).

**How can I do something similar?**

Comment: Possible duplicate https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/230540/creating-a-character-device-file

Comment: Have a look at `udev`. Write custom rules to create device nodes as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way that works for me, one that doesn't use udev rules (I'd rather do it programmatically). This is easier than I thought earlier.

1. `alloc_chrdev_region` for number of devices.
2. Create classes for each device (each with different names)
3. Set the classes' `devnode` field with your custom function ex: `return kasprintf(GFP_KERNEL, "name/%d", global++);`. This is where the naming happens. Udev should honor this function.
4. Create cdevs with `cdev_init` && `cdev_add` and set their fops.
5. Create devices with `device_create` (parent is NULL)

Note that there is no device hierarchy here, just independent devices which happen to be in the same /dev/ directory. The names specified in steps 2-5 will end up in /sys/.

Comment: There is no need to create a class for each device. Just use one main class and prefix the device's name given the `devnode` function. But I will give you a +1 for pointing me towards `devnode`. Also, when calling `create_device` or one of its extensions, you can specify the name as a path directly.